# Multi row in same table updating with case in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I can update my database vertically but how about horizontally in the same time ?

My code below here

```
UPDATE energy SET nov = CASE
WHEN label = 'myLabel' THEN '123'
WHEN label = 'myLabel2' THEN '123'
ELSE nov
END WHERE uname='123' AND years='2558'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you  mean many fiels in a row:

```
    UPDATE   energy
   SET   nov =
            CASE
               WHEN label = 'myLabel' THEN '123'
               WHEN label = 'myLabel2' THEN '123'
               ELSE nov
            END
       , nov2 =
            CASE
               WHEN label2 = 'myLabel' THEN '3123'
               WHEN label2 = 'myLabel2' THEN '3123'
               ELSE nov2
            END
 WHERE   uname = '123' AND years = '2558'
```

Comment: Thanks anyway, it's work.

Before that I use this

SET nov,nov2 CASE  WHEN label = 'myLabel' THEN ('123','123')
               WHEN label = 'myLabel2' THEN ('123','123')
               ELSE nov
            END WHERE   uname = '123' AND years = '2558'

Even this

(nov=case......'2558,nov2=case...'2558')

That's why I fail

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this..

```
UPDATE energy
 SET nov =
(select  CASE
WHEN label = 'myLabel' THEN '123'
WHEN label = 'myLabel2' THEN '123'
ELSE nov
END  as case)
WHERE uname='123' AND years='2558'
```